# jQuery function execution order

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am having a problem, or perhaps a lack of understanding, with the jQuery execution order of `$.get()` function. I want to retrieve some information from a database server to use in the `$.ready()` function. As you all know, when the get returns, it passes the data to a return handler that does something with the data. In my case I want to assign some values to variables declared inside the ready handler function. But the problem is, the return handler of `$.get()` does not execute until after ready has exited. I was wondering if (a) am I doing this right/is there a better way or if (b) there was a way around this (that is, force the get return handler to execute immediately or some other fix I'm not aware of). I have a feeling this is some closure thing that I'm not getting about JavaScript.

As per request, I'll post an example of what I mean:

```
$(function() {
    var userID;

    $.get(uri, function(returnData) {
                   var parsedData = JSON.parse(returnData);
                   userID = parsedData.userID;
               });
  });
```

So as you can see, I'm declaring a variable in ready. Then using a get call to the database to retrieve the data needed. Then I parse the JSON that is returned and assign the userID to the variable declared before. I've tested it with a couple alerts. An alert after the get shows userID as undefined but then an alert in get's return handler shows it to be assigned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$.get() is asynchronous. You have to use a callback to fill your variable and do the computation after the request is complete. Something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $.get( "yourUrl", function( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) {
        var myData = data; // data contains the response content
        // perform your processing here...
        registerHandlers( myData ); // you can only pass "data" off course...
    });

});

// your function to register the handlers as you said you need to.
function registerHandlers( data ) {
    // registering handlers...
}
```

Comment: So if I want to do meaningful things with the data, I need to do EVERYTHING in the callback? Like I can't use the get to simple assign the variable then do stuff with it in ready?

Comment: If you want a synchronous behavior (top down execution), you will need to use asynch: false in $.ajax function as **des** said, but it is not a good approach. If I were you, I would use the callback as I said. Just create a new function that receives the data as a parameter and work in it if you don't want to insert to much code inside the callback.

Comment: Ah ok well it makes more sense I guess. Well the reason I need the data from the callback to be assigned is I wanted to register UI event handlers in ready as well and that data is needed for parts of the handler. Is ok then to just register those in the get callback?

Comment: Yes, it is ok, no problem at all. You will call $.get inside ready too. I updated my code.

Comment: Ah ok thank you very much. The async thing is confusing but it makes sense to not wait for things and just continue loading the page. I'll just move all my event handlers that depend on the information to get callback.

Answer (score 3):

`$.get` is an ajax request. *A* in AJAX stand for *asynchronous*, so script won't wait for this request to finish, but instead will proceed further with your code.

You can either use complete callback or you can use [$.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and set **`async`** to **`false`** to perform synchronous request.

Comment: They say that setting async to false has been depreciated. Is this bad? Or still safe to use?

Comment: @Perley: As I said in my comment in my answer, I think you should not use. What is the problem with the callback?

Comment: They say **As of jQuery 1.8, the use of async: false is deprecated.**. Current version is 1.7.2 so it's OK **for now**, but it will be removed in 1.8. **I wouldn't use** it anyway, try working on your script so it will work with async requests

Comment: Just to complement. If you use asynch false, your browser will "freeze" until the request complets (successfully or not).

Answer (score 1):

The $.get() function executes an async httprequest, so the callback function will be executed whenever this request returns something. You should handle this callback outside of $.ready()

Maybe if you explain exactly what do you want to do, it would be easier to help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var variable1, variable 2;
    $.get('mydata.url', function(data){
        variable1 = data.mydata1;
        variable2 = data.mydata2;
    });
});
```

If you declare the variables first, then you can set their values within the get call. You can add a function call at the end of the get handler to call a separate function using these values? Without some kind of example, its hard to go into any more detail.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the full code, my guess is that you should declare your variable *outside* `$.ready`; initialize it in `ready` for the initial page load; then update it from the `get` callback handler.

for example

```
var x = ""; // declaration

$(document).ready(function() { x = "initial value"; });

$.get(...).success(function() { x = "updated from ajax"; });
```